# Finding and replacing part of a line using variables in shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file with several of lines with following format:

```
#ABC-1X1X-XXX-8000-2AB-XXXX-3000                $(var1) $(var2) $(var3) $(var4)
```

After looking for `ABC-1X1X-XXX-8000-2AB-XXXX-3000` I need to remove `#` and update the file. Run few other commands and revert it back to original.

I tried below, but with this it removes `#` but also removes all of my other variable, remainder of the line.  I only want `#` removed from that line nothing else.

```
look_for=ABC-1X1X-XXX-8000-2AB-XXXX-3000
found=($(grep $look_for $file))
sed  -i "/$found/c \\$look_for" $file
```

**output:**

```
ABC-1X1X-XXX-8000-2AB-XXXX-3000                    (missing all other variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

```
sed -i "s/$found/$look_for/g" "$file"
```